# Upgrade linux with a python script

Tags: python, linux, input, console, upgrade

I want to upgrade my linux system with a python script. But I don't know how to send Y or Enter to the console.

This is my code:

```
sudo_password = 'password'
command = 'apt-get update'
os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudo_password, command))
command = 'apt-get upgrade'
os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudo_password, command))
```

EDIT:

I want to run the script automated, therefore I don't want to use raw_input() or input().

Comment: Have you seen [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/4.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could add the `-y` parameter to your `apt-get` command. Like this:

```
...
command = 'apt-get upgrade -y'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw_input` function

e.g.

```python
user_input = raw_input('Enter Y ')
```

Comment: Please see my EDIT. Thank you